# Problema al validar que solo existan campos con letras usando regex

Tags: java, regex

Tengo un método que valida los formatos de entrada y dentro tengo una expresión regular que solo acepte letras de la a-z. El problema es que lo pruebo con solo letras pero no funciona, me devuelve `false` en el primer if. Les dejo el código acá abajo:

```
public boolean formato() {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-z].*");
    Pattern numero = Pattern.compile("[0-9].*");
    //solo campos con letra
    Matcher nombre = p.matcher(txtrut.getText());
    Matcher apellido_m = p.matcher(txtapellido_m.getText());
    Matcher apellido_p = p.matcher(txtapellido_p.getText());
    Matcher sector = p.matcher(txtsector.getText());

    //solo campos numericos
    Matcher t_zapato=numero.matcher(txtzapato.getText());
    Matcher t_pantalon=numero.matcher(txtpantalon.getText()); 
    Matcher t_chaqueta=numero.matcher(txtchaqueta.getText());
    Matcher fono=numero.matcher(txtfono.getText());
    Matcher nro=numero.matcher(txtnro_casa.getText());

    //aqui en este mensaje devuelve false 
    System.out.println("el nombre es: "+nombre.matches());

    if(nombre.matches()==false) { System.out.println(" nombre incorrecto"); return false; }
    else if (apellido_m.matches()==false) { System.out.println("apellido_m incorrecto"); return false; }
    else if (apellido_p.matches()==false) { System.out.println("apellido_p incorrecto");return false; }
    else if(sector.matches()==false) { System.out.println("sector incorrecto");return false;}
    else if(t_zapato.matches()==false) { System.out.println("zapato incorrecto"); return false;}
    else if (t_pantalon.matches()==false) { System.out.println("pantalon incorrecto");  return false;}
    else if (t_chaqueta.matches()==false) { System.out.println("chaqueta incorrecta");return false;}
    else if( fono.matches()==false) { System.out.println("fono incorrecta");return false;}
    else if(nro.matches()==false) { System.out.println("nro de casa incorrecto");return false;}
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Y con que dato comprobaste tu código? Para empezar asegurate que tomas los valores de los campos que quieres, `txtrut` no me suena como nombre, mas como algo tipo "123456-K"

Comment: perdon si me equivoque de textbox era txtnombre. gracias hay me funciono

Comment: Hay que tener en cuenta que `[a-z]+` no aceptará espacios, vocales acentuadas, `ñ`, apóstrofes, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que estas probando un campo rut que probablemente contendra numeros revisa tu codigo

ademas como informacion adicional te puedo decir que

RegExp:

```
[a-z] <= Solo Minúsculas
[A-Z] <= Solo Mayusculas
[a-zA-Z] <= Minusculas y Mayusculas
.* <= Cualquier Cosa
```

Si solo quiere aceptar Letras tienes que usar.

```
[a-zA-Z]+ <= 1 o mas letras.
[a-zA-Z]* <= 0 o mas letras.
```

Lo mismo con los Números.

```
[0-9]+ <= 1 o mas Números.
[0-9]* <= 0 o mas Números.
```

Comment: @josemigueljara Porque lo aceptaste entonces? Así otros van a pensar que la respuesta te solucionó tu problema. Si quieres valorar una respuesta util, puedes votar, pero es recomendable de solamente aceptar preguntas que te soluciónan lo que planteaste en tu pregunta.

Comment: @StefanNolde me imagino que acepto la respuesta porque lo pudo adaptar a sus necesidades. Saludos.

Comment: @Edulynch tu respuesta esta buena, pero al fin no tuvo nada que ver con el problema de la pregunta. Si necesitas la reputación, deberías editarla incorporando lo que dije en el comentario sobre asegurarse que uno compruebe los campos que uno quiere comprobar.

Comment: uno es libre de valorar lo que cree que es correcto, ademas la respuesta esta bien dirigida al problema.

Comment: @josemigueljara Mirándolo objetivamente: ¿la respuesta actual responde tu pregunta, resuelve tu problema o no?

Comment: Si la responde por que en el fondo necesitaba saber si estaba bien la expresión regular para que solo valide letras, Es cierto que había un error en una variable pero en realidad fue lo de menos. el que vea esta pregunta le quedara muy claro como hacer una expresión regular que solo valide letras y creo que eso es lo importante.

Comment: @josemigueljara entonces salva la pregunta y corrige el error de buscar letras en un campo de rut, y borra el comentario que no te funcionó ;) Por favor, entiende que la meta de SO es de generar preguntas con respuestas que no solamente solucionan un problema para ti, pero que luego sirven como fuente de soluciones de usuarios que enfrentan problemas parecidos o iguales. **Eso** es lo importante.

Comment: @StefanNolde corregi la respuesta y agrege lo que faltaba. solo falta que la revisen los pares la edicion que hice

Comment: Yo como tu hubiera editado la pregunta, pero así también funciona. falta borrar tu comentario que no funcionó ;) así se ve si fuera real

Comment: @josemigueljara de acuerdo. En el futuro, considera que aceptar una respuesta pero comentarle con "lo hice pero no funciona", la respuesta no es editada y no hay algún comentario rectificando que sí funciona deja un poco de intriga si en verdad la respuesta sirvió.